# Creating a Qt child after adding its parent to a QGraphicsScene makes it immobile

Tags: python, qt, qt5, pyqt5

If you add a `QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem` to a `QGraphicsScene`, it is mobile.
If you assign it to have a `QtWidgets.QGraphicsItemGroup` as a parent, then add the parent to the scene, it is mobile.

It becomes immobile if you add the parent to the scene BEFORE adding the child. Why?

Below is a self-contained example. If you run the code, you'll notice that you can create four `Point`s, all of which are mobile, then after its parent is added on the fifth `Point`, it becomes immobile. This was not the case in Qt4.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGraphicsView,\                      
                             QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsItem)
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class Point(QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super(Point, self).__init__(0,0,10,10)
        self.setPos(pos)
        self.setFlags(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | \
                      QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)

class Graphics(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Graphics, self).__init__()
        self.numPoints = 0
        self.polygon = QtWidgets.QGraphicsItemGroup()

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        pass

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(0,0,300,300)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        pos = event.pos()
        itemAt = self.scene().itemAt(pos, QtGui.QTransform())

        # If nothing is under the mouse, create a new point and accept the event
        if not isinstance(itemAt, Point):
            # Add the point to the scene and set its parent
            pt = Point(pos)
            pt.setParentItem(self.polygon)
            if pt.scene() is None:
                self.scene().addItem(pt)
            else:
                print "The item was implicitly added to the scene by its parent"

            # On the fifth point, add the polygon to the scene
            self.numPoints += 1
            if self.numPoints == 4:
                self.scene().addItem(self.polygon)

            event.accept()
        super(Graphics, self).mousePressEvent(event)

class MainWindow(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        scene.addItem(Graphics())
        scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 300, 300)
        self.setScene(scene)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()

    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> A QGraphicsItemGroup is a special type of compound item that treats itself and all its children as one item (i.e., all events and geometries for all children are merged together). It's common to use item groups in presentation tools, when the user wants to group several smaller items into one big item in order to simplify moving and copying of items.

Since all the `Point(s)` inside `self.polygon` are treated as single object, this object need to be Movable itself:

`self.polygon.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)`

If you want your "points" to be movable inside their parent `QGraphicsItemGroup` is not the right choice, instead you can use a `GraphicsRectItem` or a `QGraphicsPolygonItem` and others